Creating macro variables based on data from dataset
I need to create a number of macro-variables based on data from a parameter dataset.
Example:
m_v_content  m_v_name
5            macro_a
6            macro_b
30           macro_c

Expected output
3 macro-variables (or as much rows as the table contains) with the names macro_a, macro_b and macro_c where macro_a=5, macro_B=6 and macro_c=30
I tried the folowing but I was unsuccessful:
data _null_;
set have;
array cont [*] m_v_content;
array name [*] $ m_v_name;
do i=1 to dim(name);
call symputx(name[i],cont[i]);
%put name[i]=&name[i];
end;
run;


the solution is much simpler:
data null;
set have;
call symputx(m_v_name,m_v_content);
run;

Does it have to be a, b, c as suffixes? Why not 1, 2, 3?

The %put will NOT display the value at DATA Step run-time.  You would need a macro loop to iterate through macro variable whose name is formed according to some pattern.

Code is  bit more basic. The SET statement will create the automatic loop.
data _null_;

set have;

call symputx(m_v_name, m_v_content);

run;

%put &macro_a;
%put &macro_c;


